# Why aren't my styles being applied when the input has a value?

Tags: javascript, html

Am validating HTML 5 textbox. if value is not present while submitting the form, i just want to highlight that textbox borederColor to `red`. if value is present, i want to go with default behavior of the text box.

Please find my code below. Am able to show the borderColor as `red` if value is not present. But, am not able to reset the default behavior of textbox (like default bordercolor) when value is present in the textbox. Am not sure, what is going wrong here.

```
var check = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
if ( check == "") {
    document.getElementById('first_name').style.borderColor = "red";
} else {
    document.getElementById('first_name').style.borderColor = "#eee";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "default behavior when value is present"? What does the code do that you don't want it to, or what doesn't it do that you want it to? See [ask], and please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Off topic tip: This alone is not an accessible approach to validation. Users with color blindness or visual impairment won't get any feedback.

Comment: Please show your markup. Are you using a placeholder? You might find it more useful to add and remove a class. This allows you to conditionally apply styles instead of trying to remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only following code is working for me.

```
var check = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
    if (check == "") {
          document.getElementById('first_name').style.borderColor = "red";
    } else {
          document.getElementById('first_name').style.borderColor = "";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
var check = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
if (check == "") {
    document.getElementById('first_name').style.borderColor = "red";
} else {
    document.getElementById('first_name').style.borderColor = "initial";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need JS for this

```
<style>/*only need one of these for all your inputs*/
input:invalid {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
</style>

<input type="text" required/>
```

Further reading at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind an event listener `onchange`

```
var el = document.getElementById('first_name');

el.addEventListener('onchange', function(){
  var check = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
  if ( check == "") {
    document.getElementById('first_name').style.borderColor = "red";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('first_name').style.borderColor = "#eee";
  }
})
```